# How to react to the end of a Thread

Tags: android

I have a log-in-Thread and while it is running i want to show up kind of a "loading-circle". So how can i recognize when the thread ends and react to it?

```
loadingcicle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Thread t = new Thread(new Einloggen());
        t.start();
//and at the end
loadingcicle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the asynctask pattern.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

something like

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
  protected void onPreExecute() {
    showProgress(true);
  }
  protected void void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    hidProgress(true); 
  }
  protected Void doInBackground(Void...voids) {
    doMyBackgroundStuff();
  }
}.executeOnExexutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
```

of course you should be aware of activity lifecycle events and check that you are at least started or resumed before updating the ui.

Answer (score 0):

You could instantiate a Handler object on your activity and pass it to your Einloggen class. So with this handler you can call Handler.post() to execute commands on UIThread.

Look at this reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Answer (score 0):

```
final android.os.Handler mHandler = new android.os.Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what){
                case 1:
                    //
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Responded !!!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //do whatever you want here


            mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
        }
    }).start();
```